# expressjs POST header parameters?

Tags: javascript, post, node.js, express

I'm not posting to the body, and the key/value pairs do not show up anywhere I've looked when doing a curl post from PHP -- where are they?!

Update:

Using http_build_query($parameters) in the curl post worked, as they then became available in req.body, but it just seems odd that sinatra, play, and other web api frameworks all handle the posted array the same (w/o the http_build_query method), and express seems like the bastard stepchild.  Whom is in the right?

The app.js has config:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

The call:

```
app.post('/call/:genericUrlParam', function(req, res){

    // where is 'key'/'value' pair?!
    console.log('headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

});
```

The php looks like:

```
        $parameters = array (
            'key' => 'value'
        );


        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/call/myparam");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        $error = curl_error($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        if (empty($buffer)) {
            return "Error: ".$error;
        } else {
            return $buffer;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

bodyParser fills `Request.body` from POST request parameters only if header `Content-type` of the request has value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If request has no paramenters or different content type, Request.body object will be undefined.